# How to instance objects on an animated mobius strip?

Tags: animation, curve-modifier

This is a follow-up question to this one: [How to animate objects along a mobius strip?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259289/how-to-animate-objects-along-a-mobius-strip)

Thanks again for all your helpful answers! Now I'm struggling with adding static objects to my scene. I have created the mobius strip based on a bezier circle (plus array and curve modifier) that is animated via shape keys. Cars are following the curve nicely.

But how can I add for example road signs or vegetation to the road without being stretched due to the curve modifier? I tried this [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier) but it would only work with single objects like a tree. In the screenshot I used some cones on a plane as dummies.

When I scatter anything on the the geo driven by the curve modifier it gets stretched. If I use a proxy plane and then scatter on it the scattered objects move around when animation is running.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the blend file from [How to animate objects along a mobius strip?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259289/how-to-animate-objects-along-a-mobius-strip) and extended it by geometry nodes to make some trees.

So i doubled the circle and used a longer line so the "street" is a bit broader. Then i converted it to a mesh and gave it some subdivisions and made a vertex group like this:

[image]

Then i used this sub-node tree to distribute the trees and to align the trees to the right direction.

[image]

The main node tree:

[image]

I had to call the subnode tree twice to instantiate the objects on both sides, so i just flipped the geometry and instantiated again.

Result:

[image]

blend file:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much :) I tried geo nodes as well but couldn't get my head around how to instance geo only in certain areas.

Comment: glad i can help