# Geo nodes: Why are objects instanced on a curve jiggling/jumping one by one?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

Please see attached blend file for the setup.

[demo scene](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wv46a4j9crc3gbh/demo_scene.blend?dl=0)

It's a mobius strip with instanced objects on a rotating curve (using shape keys). Here's how I did it: [How to animate objects along a mobius strip?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259289/how-to-animate-objects-along-a-mobius-strip)
The moving objects are removed in this demo scene.
[image]

The instanced objects are jiggling one by one. It happens with any kind of object. It seems to be working as intended without the transform modifier, or maybe it's just not as apparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are re-subdividing your curve with `Curve to Points` before applying the `Instance on Points` node.

The `Curve to Points` node subdivides the curve with the specified value if you have selected *Count*. This leads to an interpolation of your points that do not coincide with the points predefined by the resolution of your curve.

To fix this, you would have to change the `Curve to Points` node to *Evaluated*, and before that hook in the `Resample Curve` node with the desired number of subdivisions. This will change the resolution of your curve before you evaluate the curve points, and the result will look like you would expect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the solved the issue! Didn't know what "evaluated" does but now I do :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Should be a luck of precise then line converted into points. Increasing original curve resolution solves the problem:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It does help but not a 100%. Using "evaluated" and "resample" works better :)